# How can I stop my corporate workstation from being forcefully restarted?

Tags: windows

I have a problem, every few days my company restarts my workstation, and I keep losing work because of this. I opened a support ticket with the support team, but they have no idea how to stop it from happening (typical).

I know that they're not using the `shutdown` command to restart my PC, because running `shutdown -a` doesn't stop it from happening.

I was thinking maybe someone has made a "keep alive" app to stop anything from restarting my workstation, so that I can restart it myself when I'm ready to do so (i.e. after I've saved my work, etc). Because of the work I do (I'm a programmer) it's not always possible to save what I'm doing (e.g. if I'm in the middle of debugging something complicated).

Maybe I can intercept and block some sort of shutdown message in the winapi (though this discussion would me more suited to Stack Overflow).

Comment: Does it happen regularly? Is it Windows updates?

Comment: This is not caused by Windows updates. I'm not sure what application is causing my PC to restart - it could be the anti-virus. I was hoping there was something that could just block Windows from restarting. I believe that fixing the "root cause" is out of my hands.

Comment: If you unplug the network cable, does it still do it? It could be a remote administration system... Just trying to rule out things you can't control.

Comment: Have you checked the system event logs?

Comment: You could write an app that stops it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376876(VS.85).aspx

Comment: if support has 'no idea' why suspect it is them?  overheating, ram, hardware, drivers all could be causes. is there a warning prior to the restart?

Comment: Sorry CarlF  Missed your comment What do the event logs say? If there is something sneding a restart or shutdown command, it should be recorded. How about a s cheduled event on the local system? If nothing, then look to the hardware as mentioned by @datatoo

Comment: @Michael Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @datatoo Because there is a timeout dialogue displayed 5 hours before restarting, I used process explorer to determine what process this belonged to, and it was the anti-virus (killing this process does not prevent the restart). I'm 100% certain the IT department is unwittingly restarting my PC. However, I don't believe it's wise to assume this is the only way my PC can be restarted by them, so I need a blanket fix, such as the one Michael has suggested.

Comment: Hi! I know that I'm not helping, but they did same thing using group policy options in my university. I don't know exact options that need to be used and I don't have windows server at the moment, but I know that it's there and that it can 100% be configured.

Comment: If you get a box from an anti-virus exactly 5h before. Then it suggests it's an anti-virus issue.  Killing the process may not help because anti-virus software can be quite dug into a system.  This sounds like an issue specific to the anti-virus software.  You could contact the anti-virus support. Or, don't just go to support and say "your fault". Go to them and -show- them that this anti-virus dialog box comes up exactly 5h before, so it's likely an anti-virus issue and they can contact the anti-virus people..

Comment: Sometimes IT Depts hae better access to software tech support  'cos they've paid for telephone technical support from them, and also companys often use network anti-virus software.. where a server(as in 1 centralized computer) runs the scan on all computers.  It may be a setting on the server that is doing it. But anti-virus specific technical support would know about that.. You haven't mentioned what the anti-virus software is.  obviously the specific text of this timeout message would be relevant..

Comment: even if it's not a anti-virus issue.. then maybe what the timeout is timing out on, is relevant .. but you could see what happens if the anti-virus is uninstalled.. see what happens in safe mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the application yourself, and catch the [WM_QUERYENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376876(VS.85).aspx) message.
[This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/delay/give-your-computer-insomnia-free-tool-and-source-code-to-temporarily-prevent-a-machine-from-going-to-sleep) program apparently stops a system from going to Sleep, but I don't think that would suffice.

Comment: I will try it at least.

Comment: @nbolton: sweet :) I think that the author of the Insomniac program made the source available, so you could study that as well.